# Automatic Github polling in JIRA

Tags: github, jira, dvcs

I have DVCS account in place. How do I make it update periodically without clicking being?

All the time commits from Github are appearing by JIRA issues after i manually click Synchronize in DVCS accounts administration.
How can I make it happen automatically?

Comment: You could try Atlassian Support, this is not a development issue, so they will likely answer.

Comment: @Koshinae: It's there also( https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/33146098/i-have-dvcs-account-in-place.-how-do-i-make-it-update-periodically-without-clicking-being ). I thought here could be some developer who was experiencing same thing and actually did solve it at the end. But still thanks for recommendation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer from support was to make a Webhook from the Github side. Automatic polling from JIRA side is done once per hour and this interval can't be changed since JIRA 6.3. Anyway there is JIRA DVCS Connector issue to vote it back into the JIRA -- https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/DCON-379.

Also I was provided with KB article which describes why and how to do it -- https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRAKB/Slow+Appearing+Commits+from+BitBucket+or+GitHub+in+JIRA